# Android goldfish 3.18 ARM

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-kernel

I just see that Google was add goldfish_armv7_defconfig to the 3.18 kernel, when I compile the kernel, there is no error. But when I launch it in the emulator I got just a black screen and the device stay "offline"!

Compilation:

```
$ make ARCH=arm goldfish_armv7_defconfig
$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- menuconfig # I enable overlayfs and loadable modules
$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- -j32
```

Anyone can help please!

Answer (score 0):

Emulator (the "emulator" binary in the SDK) should have the argument "-show-kernel" to see kernel messages or you can pass QEMU-specific arguments such as "-qemu -serial stdio". Worst case you can enable GDB server in QEMU and debug the kernel using GDB (look up how to do it with QEMU).
It might be that they added the support but are not using it so the first step would be to obtain the kernel messages to see what's going on.